# Filter out oldest item when items have the same name

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Foo
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Year {get; set;}
}
```

Say i have a List of Foo items.
It is possible that some Foo items have the same name. In that case i want to filter out all but the most recent Foo item with that name.
( A Foo item can not have the same name AND the same Year )

Is there way to do this with a single LINQ statement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GroupBy`:

```
var result = items.GroupBy(foo => foo.Name)
                  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(foo => foo.Year).First())
                  .ToList();
```

Comment: @octavioccl - Thanks a lot but it was almost the same, you provided more wordy explanation in addition to the code so in a way you were fastest - again thanks.